# Как установить UTF-8 в hibernate

Tags: sql, кодировка, hibernate, utf-8

Пишу проект с использованием hibernate, база данных hsqldb. Данные для вставки в базу(insert into...) хранятся в файле insert.sql, когда hibernate читает этот файл(c помощью MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor) русский текст записывается как кракозяблы. Нашёл что проблема с sql экстрактором который использует поток чтения (Reader), который по умолчанию не UTF-8. Исправил с помощью такого подхода(и это работает)- см.ниже, но мне сказали этот костыль удалить и сделать по-другому. М.б. кто-то с этим сталкивался, как это исправить по-другому? Помогите пожалуйста

в конфигах hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">path.CustomSqlExtractor</property>
```

класс:

```
public class CustomSqlExtractor extends MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor{   
    private final String SOURCE_CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    @Override
    public String[] extractCommands(final Reader reader){
        String[] lines = super.extractCommands(reader);
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        if (!charset.equals(Charset.forName(SOURCE_CHARSET))){
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                try{
                    lines[i] = new String(lines[i].getBytes(), SOURCE_CHARSET);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                    throw new IOError(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 5.2.3 Hibernate поддерживает указание кодировки ресурсов для создания схемы БД через [параметр](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html)

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.charset_name`

По-умолчанию его значение устанавливается равным `Charset.defaultCharset()` (кодировке виртуальной машины).